# Magento Rest Api Recaptcha Validation Failed Error

Tags: php, rest, magento, magento2

I am sending below payload in Create Customer Rest Api in Magento2 but still getting error.I dont want to turn off recaptcha from admin panel. Is there any way to bypass REcaptcha in magento.

url: {url}/index.php/rest/V1/customers

payload

```
"customer": {
    "email": "user@example.com",
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "storeId": 1,
    "websiteId": 1
},
"password": "Demo1234",
"g-recaptcha-response": "03AFcWeA4h9g8CToI6b3NRMEijISsbXgNmTQ2I_QM3ZizdEO2N-Icy1mMpPjjc8ianb6tbWSvq6zCUCygqiL4tLg3caV4Cc6UEvWwETVqAeNR5r7pp-Y8YyBzPKDyBSvK9IFWa_effuqVIHrdd9_RC3Qwij4AHQP96WHcbIqpicd6IYRhMum1QdI5R2cpVf85EYu6-dTJnschVhVtHutYgp5-WOk34GfHZaimQSDFNrIiL6XGzY41zOZWcyNZSRo6g7J2ZNAWwN9uTxrqw_WogfXX2yAWO72Mjw0opts4fEgVA8hGtYyWNTGEEl6oN5ySG4LLuYHO7SrlfwWsdcDdZRP5YJvw5847h7qbTPNo9dc3w2Ibje_PGEZVxkO65zx5jpBYWdifgrZy4wTBvhRR_kDclrTzXueGTnDn3n-gW30o6PJXx1llyX5idXAabuRosyKgGF6wdgPQBNiZo_Jcq2z3U8J_JelyoX5MigdeL4_1e-4AoGkMDJnA1gQMFRPTmVgfM0GHbrjZiHN05ueEnkcNrITPlCK76fk3XTm0mFoNgpqcqJapZa7ru1nea5AgivscMO-zmaQ-XgN1RcgVeCf2ATP7XXnZ3Tr9xuzMr7COheEGCH692OqRzbgsGquX5wqCEzZb6aI9yOtkU56e-TIsNHIsCKjmtURi-MQhf6MDmw0znikhmzo1ce0INvpbcFBoUTHo0rzx4G7KRtAnmFjmPeLBmP5efsjb69ost0F8vexY3qOEN5tgegLaHAUEZNiNYPxBlsdh0"}
```

Error

```
{
"message": "ReCaptcha validation failed, please try again"
}
```

When i turn off recaptcha from admin panel its working fine. But i dont want to turn off recaptcha. Is there any way to bypass this error

thanks in advance.

Comment: Trying to pass a `g-recaptcha-response` yourself, makes really little sense - those responses are tied to the client the captcha was solved on to begin with, as far as I know. _"But i dont want to turn off recaptcha"_ - what _exactly_ is it turned on for, currently? At which point of using your site, does the user need to solve a captcha? That an _API_ was protected by a captcha, that makes little sense to begin with - APIs _are_ for automated processes triggered by "computers" instead of humans.

Comment: CBroe Right now captcha is enbaled because it's using in Create Account Form.
But I'm implenting user registration modal with rest api so i can register the user through modal  also added recaptcha in the modal form and getting the response from recaptcha and sending in api but still not able to bypass